# Force user to enter a column in the list

Tags: list

When ever a user changes a particular field in a SharePoint List, Can I force the user to enter another field?

For example, I have got two fields, lets say A and B. When ever a user changes / update the field A can I force the user to update B as well ? (If user changes B no need to force the user to change A).

Looking for some inputs!! Many thanks ...

Comment: Are you able to use javascript/jQuery?

Comment: I did not try with that, though thanks for that, will see how can I do it ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible Out-of-box. You can use a javascript to clear the B field. If you need some logic or validation, you have to develop custom fields.

Comment: Most of the time JavaScript will work fine. However, it is worth noting that it is not bulletproof. The only bulletproof method is to write an Event Receiver.

Comment: With the question, I understand that he wants user to update field B when field A is updated(by user). If so, event receiver cannot help as it will not change the UI at the time of field change. The only option is to develop custom field control

Comment: Yes, good point about the UI. The event receiver could only enforce the data.

Comment: thank you Amit and Kit for your help on this issue !! however I would like to add one more note that the list is of type Datasheet, here also cn I use JavaScript?